# Altering an object in an ArrayList that is in the ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Client> allClients` in the `ServletContext` as `allClients`. `Client` contains an `ArrayList<Car> allCars`.

What I was wondering, if I do this:

```
allClients = (ArrayList<Client>) getServletContext.getAttribute("allClients");
Client client = allClients.get(0);
Car newCar = new Car("Audi");
client.addCar(newCar);
```

Do i have to put `allClients` back in the `ServletContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i have to put allClients back in the ServletContext?

Exactly. You need to put it back. Otherwise the attribute value remains the same as previous.

After your changes done to the collections, you need to overridden the old collection with modified value.

Comment: Better synchronize, too.  That's shared, mutable state - not thread safe.

Comment: The attribute value (i.e. the reference to the list) wouldn't change in that case anyway, would it?

Comment: @Thomas yes. it won't change, until you put it back.

Comment: What I mean is: the list is the same but you change its content. So why do you have to put it back if the _reference_ won't change? Or do you get a copy of the value instead?

Comment: @Thomas Exactly. It wont give the *orignal* object to you. A copy of it. same goes for request's `getAttribute` and `getParameter` methods.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ So if I have a method `public void addCar(Client client, Car car){ client.addCar(car); getServletContext.setAttribute("allClients", allClients);}` would suffice?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying. Is this implementation specific or is there a specification? AFAIK the JavaDoc doesn't state this.

Comment: @Thomas Yes. But it's purely personal experience :) Sorry for not providing any proof's.

Comment: @LiamdeHaas Sure. That's fine. But I would like to change the method name addCarToContext ;)